# First IIS site set-up on localhost

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have IIS 7.0 running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

I tried to Connect to Server with a server name of localhost.

It then prompts me for my login credentials.  I type in the username and password that I use to log in to this Windows machine, but I get a message

> Could not connect to the specified computer. Details: Unable to connect to the remote server

Why would it not be able to connect to the localhost?  Does my account need to have Windows Administrator privileges?

Comment: Have you tried entering http://servername in the browser, where servername is the computer name? It should come up with the default page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to have local administrator privileges, not just remote administrator.

Comment: How did you do this?